# How to install python34 module tweepy onto raspberry pi with pip

Tags: linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, pip

I am trying to install tweepy for python 3.4 on my raspberry pi, but when I run `pip install tweepy`, tweepy installs, but only for python 2.7. What is the command/procedure for installing tweepy for python 3.4?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3.4 install tweepy`.

Pip supports `pip{version}` to install packages in multiple versions.

Comment: Just tried that, given the error "-bash: pip3.4: command not found
"

Comment: What's your pip version? `pip -V`

Comment: that gives the error:     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources

Comment: when I run "sudo apt-get install python3-pip" I am told I already have the package installed?